# Import and manipulate R Scripts programmatically / Convert .R to .Rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an `R` Script that I would like to import from within a different R-script, manipulate it's content (search and replace) and save with a different extension (`.rmd`).

This is how the example.R File would look before manipulation:

```
# A title
# chunkstart
plot(1,1)
# chunkend
```

and this is how **example.Rmd** it would look after manipulation: replaced "`# chunkstart`" and "`# chunkend`" with  ```{r} and ```, respectively.

````
# A title
```{r}
plot(1,1)
```
````

I've been searching for methods to do this, but so far have found none. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure that you can do it using ***regex*** with less lines of code.
However its should solve your problem.

````
library(magrittr)

readLines('example.R') %>% 
  stringr::str_replace("# chunkstart", "```{r}") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace("# chunkend", "```") %>% 
  writeLines("example.Rmd")
````

With the following lines of code you will be able to apply this "operation" in every `.R` file inside `/path_to_some_directory`

````
lapply(list.files('/path_to_some_directory', pattern = ".R$", 
                  full.names = TRUE), function(data) {
  readLines(data) %>% 
    stringr::str_replace("# chunkstart", "```{r}") %>% 
    stringr::str_replace("# chunkend", "```") %>% 
    writeLines(paste0(data, "md"))
})
````

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think `?knitr::spin` is a relevant answer to the question (specifically asking for *ideas*), or at least a useful alternative to consider. 
You'd have to slightly reformat the input, but the benefits would be a built-in, much richer and versatile way to deal with chunk options and formatting.

Here's what an annotated R script might look like (with spin's default regexs),

```
#' ## A title
#' first chunk
#- fig.width=10
plot(1,1)
# some text
#' another chunk
plot(2,2)
```

and the output Rmd reads,

````
## A title
first chunk

```{r fig.width=10}
plot(1,1)
# some text
```

another chunk

```{r }
plot(2,2)
```
````

Comment: If you believe certain answers are getting erroneously deleted, please bring it up on [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). There are probably reasons behind it, even though they aren't always stated.

Comment: Beyond that, could you [edit] your answer to remove the derogatory remarks to SO moderation? We aim for a more formal technical style, and such remarks don't exactly fit that. (You could get away with them in chat and sometimes in comments, but not in normal questions and answers.)

Comment: I'm concerned that anonymous answerers on SO don't get a good experience – we can't comment, and answers can rapidly get nuked to oblivion with knee-jerk assumptions (if I'd posted this as a high-rep user I bet it wouldn't have been deleted). Engaging on Meta would probably reignite the typical niche-tag debate (moderators who delete concise answers often don't know the topic) that never gets anywhere.This minimally-critical note was to point out that the "technical style" failed to be considered twice, and I think it's important that readers (and the OP) be aware of such failures.

Comment: Still, I don't believe the criticism belongs in an *answer*, though. And BTW, your answer isn't really that concise in that way. (I do agree not all concise answers are *bad*.) However, I do feel it'd be *better* to let the debate re-ignite on Meta until an actual conclusion gets reached. One other case where it took a while is with canned comments - they started out very unpopular until people finally understood why it could be necessary. (Moderation is the primary use case here, and higher quality canned comments are often better than short, low-quality, rushed comments.)